# Print an object using GDB debugger by object id (i.e., 0xee63d60)

Tags: objective-c, ios, gdb, xcode4.3

Is there a way to do a "po" or print object by the object's id/memory location? For instance if I have an object with id: 0xee63d60 can I show what is in that object?  I know I can use:

(gdb) info malloc-history 0xee63d60

to get the StackTrace, which is very helpful but I would love to see what is in that object or even what it's name is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(lldb) po 0xee63d60` works for me.

Comment: Is that because you're using lldb instead of gdb?

Comment: Nope. I just tested in GDB, and I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are paused in a "break point" you can right-click an object and select Print Object.  This should print out the "description" of the object.  See +(NSString *)description of the NSObject class.  You can override this method if you need something more specific.

Hope this Helps